# python thread using only half of available cpu

Tags: python, multithreading, slowdown

I am working on a large computational problem in python. Running the problem linearly pegs one of my cpus to 100%. So I paralleled it using the threading library. The results were not so good. All of my cpus are being used, but they seem to be all maxing out at 50% utilization. Overall performance was worse than the linear program. Since my threads are all purely computational and independent, shouldn't they be taking up nearly 100% of all the cpus? Why are they running up to a 50% ceiling? Is this something built in to python?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Python has a Global Interpreter Lock which means that only one Python thread will be actively running at any given time - multiple threads allow various threads to be sleeping while another is active, but they won't be active simultaneously. You may want to look at the [`multiprocessing`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/multiprocessing.html) module instead which uses multiple interpreter processes to work around the GIL, since each process has its own GIL.